# Error Importing zip with out of the box Python3.6 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, python3, zip

I am trying to import a zip file in `python3.6`.

I was using `python2.7` to import `MIRAlib.pyc` which is a zip file and I renamed the extension as pyc. With `python2.7` I was able to import the zip without any problem. But recently I move to `python3.6` and got `zipimport.ZipImportError:`.

I tried to follow https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291737/zipimport-zipimporterror-cant-decompress-data-zlib-not-available. But no luck.

I am attaching a screenshot that explains the situation more...

[image]

**This `python3.6` is not compiled and build by me, it came with `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` out of the box. Any Idea how to fix it.**

Comment: You are trying (and failing) to import a module called "RTT". What is that module?

Comment: RTT is the module that is living inside the zip file... `MIRAlib.pyc`

Comment: So python is just complaining that it cannot find RTT,zip in the usual places it looks -- is the directory where RTT.zip lives on your PYTHONPATH or in the current directory?

Comment: Yes It is. I have appended the location of `MIRAlib.pyc` after `import sys`. And all the procedure is similar for `python2.7` and `python3.6`. All the pip package is also similar for both version of python. The problem is `python2.7` can and `python3.6` can not able to read the zip file. Its not a sourcing issue.